# PyProj - Transform coordinate in "HK80 grid" to "WGS 84 / UTM zone 49N or 49S"

Tags: python, coordinate-system, convert, pyproj, hong-kong

Am trying to use python pyproj to do the above conversion (convert/transform from Hong Kong GRID to Hong Kong UTM), but am getting different values from the expected result.

My expected conversion result is: "North **836148**, East **822745**" to "North **828672.7449**, East **12488562.2742**". See my codes below for both zones (N and S):-

```
# https://epsg.io/102141

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:2326') # PCS: Hong_Kong_1980_Grid or EPSG:102140
outProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=49 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs") # PCS: Hong_Kong_1980_UTM_Zone_49N or EPSG:102141
# outPro = Proj(init='epsg:102141') # This returns RuntimeError

# Expected result: 828672.7449, 12488562.2742

x1, y1 = 822745, 836148
# x1, y1 = 836148, 822745


x2, y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
print (x2, y2)
```

Or

```
# https://epsg.io/32749

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:2326') # PCS: Hong_Kong_1980_Grid or epsg:102140
# outProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=49 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") # PCS: Hong_Kong_1980_UTM_Zone_49S or EPSG:32749
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:32749')

# Expected result: 828672.7449, 12488562.2742

x1, y1 = 822745, 836148
# x1, y1 = 836148, 822745


x2, y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
print (x2, y2)
```

Could it be that my expected result is incorrect or I am missing something?
I want to certisfy the expected output by going from: "Hong_Kong_1980_Grid_System" to "Hong_Kong_1980_UTM_Zone_49N / 49S"?

```
North   East    North1      East1
836148  822745  828672.7449 12488562.27
831905  822495  827480.7854 12473200.37
838208  816918  810095.1039 12481647.01
838127  816314  805922.5972 12482194.51
837452  820146  815300.3898 12484301.71
833764  816330  808333.7182 12478896.42
841476  830964  834944.8892 12495195.37
```

The result needs to match above table from Hong Kong 1980 grid to WGS84/UTM 49S

Comment: So what values are you getting? See if epsg:2326 has an associate transformation. Otherwise, you may need to give the full +proj string in order to add +wgs84=-162.619,-276.959,-161.764,0.067753,-2.243649,-1.158827,-1.094246   That's EPSG:1825.

Comment: I am getting "813428.0173294857 12487457.442199748" even after I have provided the full +proj string as: outProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=49 +south +datum=WGS84 +wgs84=-162.619,-276.959,-161.764,0.067753,-2.243649,-1.15827,-1.094246 +units=m +no_defs") # PCS: Hong_Kong_1980_UTM_Zone_49S or EPSG:32749

Comment: i have edited the question by adding more sample target coordinates...

Comment: I don't think you can add the towgs string to the utm one,  add it to a full hk80 grid definition.

Comment: I am now sensing that getting the correct definition of "+towgs84" parameters of Hong Kong 1980_UTM_Zone_49S would solve the issue?

Comment: The pdf documents on this page: http://www.geodetic.gov.hk/smo/gsi/programs/en/GSS/grid/refdoc.htm could be usefull to anyone technically inclinef to help? Most expecially this: http://www.geodetic.gov.hk/smo/gsi/data/pdf/explanatorynotes.pdf

Comment: I think you mixed some things. x should always be East, and y North. Hongkong is in UTM zone 49N and 50N, so why you want to transform to UTM zone 49S? The "expected result" given in 49S, would fall into zone 50N. Maybe you should check lat/lon for your reference point first, or take the reference point of the last page of the document you linked, which is in UTM zone 50N. For all Hongkong 1980 based coordinates, I suggest to add the `+towgs84` parameters given by mkennedy.

Comment: @mkennedy any idea why the Hong Kong 1980 UTM 49N and 50N CRS didn't make it into the EPSG database?

Comment: @AndreJ I think when the HK80 grid was put in, EPSG wasn't asked for the UTM zones, likewise with some of the transformations--information wasn't available yet. I checked my HK folder and I only had one document on transformations, not the other ones that are now available. I'll send it all to the subcommittee.

Comment: A late reply from the subcommittee: They will not add HK80 to the EPSG database, because the local surveying authority does not want it, and there is an error in the English translation of the supplied documents (which I can not resolve).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into the area of use for each of the CRS you are using in this example.

For the two options you have suggested for the input CRS, the bounds (min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat) are (113.76, 22.13, 114.51, 22.58).

```py
>>> from pyproj import CRS
>>> CRS("ESRI:102140")
<Projected CRS: ESRI:102140>
Name: Hong_Kong_1980_Grid
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: China - Hong Kong
- bounds: (113.76, 22.13, 114.51, 22.58)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: Hong_Kong_1980_Grid
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: Hong Kong 1980
- Ellipsoid: International 1924
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
>>> CRS("epsg:2326")
<Projected CRS: EPSG:2326>
Name: Hong Kong 1980 Grid System
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: China - Hong Kong
- bounds: (113.76, 22.13, 114.51, 22.58)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: Hong Kong 1980 Grid
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: Hong Kong 1980
- Ellipsoid: International 1924
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

And for the output CRS, the only one that matches the input bounds is the Hong_Kong_1980_UTM_Zone_49N with the bounds of (113.76, 22.13, 114.51, 22.58) as the
max latitude of 0 is below the minimum latitude bounds of the input CRS.

```py
>>> CRS("epsg:32749")
<Projected CRS: EPSG:32749>
Name: WGS 84 / UTM zone 49S
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: World - S hemisphere - 108°E to 114°E - by country
- bounds: (108.0, -80.0, 114.0, 0.0)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: UTM zone 49S
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

>>> CRS("ESRI:102141")
<Projected CRS: ESRI:102141>
Name: Hong_Kong_1980_UTM_Zone_49N
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: China - Hong Kong
- bounds: (113.76, 22.13, 114.51, 22.58)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: UTM zone 49N
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: Hong Kong 1980
- Ellipsoid: International 1924
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

Using this transformer, the input differs from your expected coordinates quite a bit:

```py
>>> from pyproj import Transformer
>>> transformer = Transformer.from_crs("ESRI:102140", "ESRI:102141")
>>> transformer
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of Hong_Kong_1980_Grid + UTM zone 49N
Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
>>> transformer.definition
'proj=pipeline step inv proj=tmerc lat_0=22.3121333333333 lon_0=114.178555555556 k=1 x_0=836694.05 y_0=819069.8 ellps=intl step proj=utm zone=49 ellps=intl'
>>> transformer.transform(822745, 836148)
(813184.8023209373, 2487653.6490154588)
```

However, if you use the UTM South Zone, the coordinates are closer to what you are expecting (but still off).

```py
>>> transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:2326", "epsg:32749", always_xy=True)
>>> transformer
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: axis order change (2D) + Inverse of Hong Kong 1980 Grid + Hong Kong 1980 to WGS 84 (1) + UTM zone 49S
Area of Use:
- name: China - Hong Kong
- bounds: (113.76, 22.13, 114.51, 22.58)
>>> transformer.transform(822745, 836148)  # Expected result: 828672.7449, 12488562.2742
(813428.0173295278, 12487457.442199744)
```

Based on the results from transformation using the correct area of use for the CRS, I would assume that your expected results are incorrect.