# Convert X, Y into Latitude,Longitude with unknown system

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, hong-kong

I have a set of X, Y values that indicate some locations in Hong Kong. But I am not able to convert the X/Y into latitude/longitude since the coordinate system is unknown. Is there any way I can fit the X/Y value into many Geographic information systems to find out which system the data provider is using?

The data I have:

```
X       Y
840787  816064
839740  819091
839291  819498
840383  816178
835702  818880
833502  816629
837048  815708
838910  823019
```

Comment: Most likely this is [Hong Kong 1980 Grid System](http://epsg.io/2326) (EPSG:2326)

Comment: @FSimardGIS Thanks for your help. Hong Kong 1980 Grid System matches the dataset perfectly. http://epsg.io/ is a great tool for beginners (such as me) to learn more about the world coordinate systems

Comment: @FSimardGIS, sounds like an answer

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253227/pyproj-transform-coordinate-in-hk80-grid-to-wgs-84-utm-zone-49n-or-49s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your coordinates seem to be in EPSG:2326 (Hong Kong 1980 Grid System).

A great way to search for coordinate systems is to go to [epsg.io](http://epsg.io), there you can search registered coordinate systems by country, by code, etc. and get a preview of the coordinates with an interactive map, as well as the definition of the coordinate system.